# R: reshape dataframe from wide to long format based on compound column names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe containing observations for two sets of data (A,B), with dataset and observation type given by the column names :

```
mydf <- data.frame(meta1=paste0("a",1:2), meta2=paste0("b",1:2), 
                   A_var1 = c(11:12), A_var2 = c("p","r"), 
                   B_var1 = c(21:22), B_var2 = c("x","z"))
```

I would like to reshape this dataframe so that each row contains observations on one set only. In this long format, set and column names should by given by splitting the original column names at the '_':

```
mydf2 <- data.frame(meta1=rep(paste0("a",1:2),2), 
                  meta2=rep(paste0("b",1:2),2),
                  set=c("A","B","A","B"),
                  var1 = c(11:12),
                  var2 = c("a","b","c","d"))
```

I have tried using 'gather' in combination with 'str_split','sub', but unfortunately without success. Could this be done using tideverse functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this with `tidyverse` !

You were close, you need to `gather`, then `separate`, then `spread`.

```
new_df <- mydf %>%
  gather(set, vars, 3:6) %>%
  separate(set, into = c('set', 'var'), sep = "_") %>%
  spread(var, vars)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. However, it does generate two warning messages:
    1: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped 
    2: Using ... for passing arguments to `strsplit()` is defunct. Any way to avoid these from being generated?

Comment: glad to help. So I got the same errors. the first one is because your columns  for A_var1, A_var2 etc. are both factor, and numeric. It coerces them into character because it cant mix them. You can avoid this by first changing those columns to `character`. But it doesn't matter. The second error I realized is because I used `by = `, not `sep = `, in `separate`. I've just edited that, even though they both work. `sep = ` is correct.
Also tick the check box if you accept the answer, if you'd please! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the second phrase into 'gather(set, vars, contains("_"))' makes the solution even more general.