# melt dataframe with IDs based on start of column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with counts for different genes (Locus) on different days (d0-d24) - dX.2 is the count of the 2nd allele for a given day/locus combination. Right now this dataset is in a sort of "wide" format, with paired columns based on the prefix (dX):

```
df<-data.frame(Locus=c("Locus_1","Locus_10","Locus_100","Locus_101","Locus_102","Locus_103")
,d0.1=c(248,20,95,13,0,33),d0.2=c(252,480,405,487,500,467),
d2.1=c(252,24,84,14,0,43),d2.2=c(248,476,416,486,500,457),
d6.1=c(256,30,82,15,0,41),d6.2=c(244,470,418,485,500,459),
d10.1=c(280,21,84,18,0,36),d10.2=c(220,479,416,482,500,464))

df
      Locus d0.1 d0.2 d2.1 d2.2 d6.1 d6.2 d10.1 d10.2
1   Locus_1  248  252  252  248  256  244   280   220
2  Locus_10   20  480   24  476   30  470    21   479
3 Locus_100   95  405   84  416   82  418    84   416
4 Locus_101   13  487   14  486   15  485    18   482
5 Locus_102    0  500    0  500    0  500     0   500
6 Locus_103   33  467   43  457   41  459    36   464
```

What Id like to do is use  `reshape` (or similar, tidyr) to reformat this dataframe to the 'long' format, with variables that incorporate the day (e.g. d0) and the allele ID (.1 or .2)

i.e.

```
long.df<-reshape_code(df...)
long.df
       Locus Allele.1 Allele.2 Day
1    Locus_1      248      252   0
2   Locus_10       20      480   0
3  Locus_100       95      405   0
4  Locus_101       13      487   0
5  Locus_102        0      500   0
6  Locus_103       33      467   0
7    Locus_1      252      248   2
8   Locus_10       24      476   2
9  Locus_100       84      416   2
10 Locus_101       14      486   2
11 Locus_102        0      500   2
12 Locus_103       43      457   2
13   Locus_1      256      244   6
14  Locus_10       30      470   6
15 Locus_100       82      418   6
16 Locus_101       15      485   6
17 Locus_102        0      500   6
18 Locus_103       41      459   6
19   Locus_1      280      220  10
20  Locus_10       21      479  10
21 Locus_100       84      416  10
22 Locus_101       18      482  10
23 Locus_102        0      500  10
24 Locus_103       36      464  10
```

Perhaps using the package `nc` (named capture)? Im not quite sure where to start.
Standard code/approach  would be `reshape(df,id=c("Day","Locus",...))`  but of course there is no 'day' variable yet.

I also saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484766/r-reshape-dataframe-from-wide-to-long-format-based-on-compound-column-names) to a similar but perhaps more simple problem, using `gather` `separate` `spread` but im not sure how create the sets by Alleles 1 and 2. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -Locus, names_pattern = "d([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)", names_to = c("Day", ".value")) %>%
  rename_with(~ paste0("Allele.", .), .cols = `1`:`2`)
# # A tibble: 24 x 4
#    Locus     Day   Allele.1 Allele.2
#    <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 Locus_1   0          248      252
#  2 Locus_1   2          252      248
#  3 Locus_1   6          256      244
#  4 Locus_1   10         280      220
#  5 Locus_10  0           20      480
#  6 Locus_10  2           24      476
#  7 Locus_10  6           30      470
#  8 Locus_10  10          21      479
#  9 Locus_100 0           95      405
# 10 Locus_100 2           84      416
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
tmp <- melt(DT, id.vars = "Locus"
  )[, c("Day", "Allele") := strcapture("d([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)", variable, proto = list(Day = "", Allele = ""))
  ][, variable := NULL]
tmp <- dcast(tmp, Locus + Day ~ Allele, value.var = "value")
setnames(tmp, c("1", "2"), paste0("Allele.", c("1", "2")))
tmp
#         Locus    Day Allele.1 Allele.2
#        <char> <char>    <num>    <num>
#  1:   Locus_1      0      248      252
#  2:   Locus_1     10      280      220
#  3:   Locus_1      2      252      248
#  4:   Locus_1      6      256      244
#  5:  Locus_10      0       20      480
#  6:  Locus_10     10       21      479
#  7:  Locus_10      2       24      476
#  8:  Locus_10      6       30      470
#  9: Locus_100      0       95      405
# 10: Locus_100     10       84      416
# 11: Locus_100      2       84      416
# 12: Locus_100      6       82      418
# 13: Locus_101      0       13      487
# 14: Locus_101     10       18      482
# 15: Locus_101      2       14      486
# 16: Locus_101      6       15      485
# 17: Locus_102      0        0      500
# 18: Locus_102     10        0      500
# 19: Locus_102      2        0      500
# 20: Locus_102      6        0      500
# 21: Locus_103      0       33      467
# 22: Locus_103     10       36      464
# 23: Locus_103      2       43      457
# 24: Locus_103      6       41      459
#         Locus    Day Allele.1 Allele.2
```

Comment: why do you have `pivot_longer` + `pivot_wider`?? cant you just do `pivot_longer`??

Comment: Yep, haven't found a way to easily preface `"Allele."` to the new column names ... short of `rename`